# JavaScript Calculator Error please need fix

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple calculator. Here's what I've got:

```
<script>
  function f1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("num1");
    var y = document.getElementById("num2");
    var z = x + y;
    alert(z);
  }
</script>


<input id="num1" type="text">
<input id="num2" type="text">
<button onclick="f1()">Click</button>
```

I keep getting an error.

Comment: What error? [There's nothing causing errors in your code](http://jsfiddle.net/9phab0Ln/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` and `y` are both `HTMLElement`s, not `Number`s, so you can't simply add them together. Instead, you want to add their `value` properties together after you've converted them to `Number`s:

`var z = parseFloat(x.value) + parseFloat(y.value);`

MDN has a good article on JavaScript types that might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the values of those inputs.

```
function f1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var z = x + y;
    alert(z);
  }
```

for detail see *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)*.